# D5 library folder (not the Library Paths)

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

just had a crash with an SSD (a days work went missing!) and have had to go back to a HDD.

I have just installed D5 on the HDD and would like to try and find the Library Paths file so I can just copy it all across. There are about 40 Path-entries in it.

Using a USB adapter I searched the SSD for file contents with a fragment of a Path that the file contains but it came up zip.

```
$(DELPHI)\Lib;$(DELPHI)\Bin;
```

Can anyone one please point me at where the Library Paths are actually stored?

Thank you.

Comment: If I remember it correctly, the Library Paths are stored in the Windows registry along with other Delphi settings.

Comment: For future reference it's not a bad idea to export and SAVE Your registry settings to a file which you then back up.    Too late now!  I keep a file called libpaths.txt in my source code repo that contains reference versions of these library paths.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Library Paths file".

The `$(DELPHI)` part of what you quoted refers to your Delphi installation root (base) folder, which in the case of Delphi 5 defaults to `C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi5`, so the `$(DELPHI)\Lib` folder would be `C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi5\Lib`.

This path information is configured when you install Delphi, and is stored in the Windows Registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi\5.0\RootDir` for Delphi 5.

The "about 40 paths" probably refers to what you've configured in `Tools->Environment Options->Library->Library Path`; that information is also saved in the Windows Registry. If you can't boot Windows from the SSD drive, you're out of luck; you need to start Windows and then use `RegEdit` to export that key from the registry in order to recover that information. You'll need to reinstall your third-party components, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Ken's answer, if the SSD is readable and mounted as an additional drive you can get the registry settings: **DISCLAIMER:** This is mainly from memory, but I have done this in a similar situation.

- Copy NTUSER.DAT from `(SSD):\Users\<username>` to a "safe place". You will have to uncheck the "Hide protected operating system files" option from Explorer Folder Options, or use the command line for this.
- Run regedit. Select the HKEY_USERS key, the use File -> Load Hive and select the NTUSER.dat file uou copied from the old drive.
- Hopefully this will load your registry settings from the old computer into a new key under HKEY_USERS
- Find Software\Borland\Delphi\5.0\ in the new hive, then export whatever subkeys you need to a .reg file
- Tweak the exported file(s) - you will need to change the key names to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi...\*
- Unload the registry hive
- Backup your existing HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi reg key
- Check then import the tweaked registry file

This is almost a question for SuperUser!